# How can I add an Apply button to a menu in Android?

Tags: android

My live wallpaper has a few settings. I used the cube live wallpaper tutorial to implement the settings list: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/index.html

Everything works, however when I select a setting, it simply takes me back to the menu option. From there I have to press back on the phone to go back to the screen where I can select "Set Wallpaper" or "Settings". I want to add an "OK" or "Back" button that would produce the same result (for convenience purposes). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. finish() does the trick :)